# Neo4J ETL Tool mapping and data transfer takes a lot of time

Tags: neo4j, cypher, etl, graph-databases

I'm testing the Neo 4J ETL Tool with several MySQL and MSSQL databases and so far mapping and data transfer takes a long time to the point that for some I can't get the mapping done and for none I have been able to finish the data transfer. The details below:

Target Database: Neo4j Graph database version 5.1.0
Processor: Intel(R) Xeon(R) Gold 5217 CPU @ 3.00GHz 2.99 GHz (2 processors)
Ram: 64GB
Windows 10
For all tests, I see the Zulu Platform x64 Architecture running with significant CPU and Memory usage.

**Test 1&2: MySQL and MSSQL database stuck on data transfer**

After mapping and discarding some tables, I tested both import online import modes with the default configuration (Unwind Row Size: 1000, Transaction Batch Size: 10000): The process is stuck at

> - Creating nodes with label DspIexGmp

since more than 24h. The table itself has a size of 100MB, the database in total a size of 400 MB. The MSSQL database is on the same machine (localhost). The MySQL on another machine in the network.

**Test 3: MSSQL database stuck on mapping**

For a different MSSQL database, the mapping is stuck since 10h after the following lines:

> - Crawling routines
> - Retrieved 0 routines
> - Not retrieving synonyms, since this was not requested
> - Not retrieving sequences, since this was not requested

Server is hosted on a server in the local network

The Neo4j log gives me always the same lines over and over again during either tests mapping and data transfer:

> [2022-10-28 13:15:56.009] [info] Online check request:
> https://dist.neo4j.org/neo4j-desktop/win/latest.yml [2022-10-28
> 13:15:56.073] [info] Online check response: 200 version: 1.5.2 files

And sometimes

> [2022-10-28 12:57:10.949] [info]  Graph App[neo4j-browser-id]: Checking 5.0.0 for suitable desktop API version
> [2022-10-28 12:57:10.952] [info]  Graph App[neo4j-browser-id]: Version 5.0.0 satisfied. { desktopApiVersion: '1.4.0', packageDesktopApiVersion: '^1.4.0' }
> [2022-10-28 12:57:10.956] [info]  Graph App[f72f3631-b844-48c0-81ec-c2591b9c0852]: Checking 1.5.1 for suitable desktop API version
> [2022-10-28 12:57:10.958] [info]  Graph App[f72f3631-b844-48c0-81ec-c2591b9c0852]: Version 1.5.1 satisfied. { desktopApiVersion: '1.4.0', packageDesktopApiVersion: '^1.4.0' }
> [2022-10-28 12:57:10.960] [info]  Graph App[neo4j-bloom-id]: Checking 2.5.1 for suitable desktop API version
> [2022-10-28 12:57:10.962] [info]  Graph App[neo4j-bloom-id]: Version 2.5.1 satisfied. { desktopApiVersion: '1.4.0', packageDesktopApiVersion: '^1.4.0' }
> [2022-10-28 12:57:11.069] [info]  Graph App[neo4j-bloom-id]: Checking 2.5.1 for suitable desktop API version
> [2022-10-28 12:57:11.072] [info]  Graph App[neo4j-bloom-id]: Version 2.5.1 satisfied. { desktopApiVersion: '1.4.0', packageDesktopApiVersion: '^1.4.0' }
> [2022-10-28 12:57:11.078] [warn]  Failed to parse manifest file for Graph-App[neo4j-bloom]. Error: Graph-App[neo4j-bloom] does not contain manifest.json
> at getManifest (C:\Users\XXX\AppData\Local\Programs\Neo4j Desktop\resources\app.asar\dist\main.prod.js:3828:15)
> at async LocalProcessor.resolveConfig (C:\Users\XXX\AppData\Local\Programs\Neo4j Desktop\resources\app.asar\dist\main.prod.js:4268:30)
> at async LocalProcessor.downloadUpdate (C:\Users\XXX\AppData\Local\Programs\Neo4j Desktop\resources\app.asar\dist\main.prod.js:4496:45)
> [2022-10-28 12:57:11.080] [warn]  update version: 2.5.1 already downloaded for neo4j-bloom
> [2022-10-28 12:57:38.066] [info]  Online check request: https://dist.neo4j.org/neo4j-desktop/win/latest.yml
> [2022-10-28 12:57:38.135] [info]  Online check response: 200 version: 1.5.2

Does anyone have any ideas what can help? I am open to alternative solutions on how to import a existing database to Neo4j but have very limited knowledge about how to do so.

Thanks in advance!

If more information is required feel free to ask, I can also send the full logs both from the Tool and the Desktop Application.

Comment: Try using the command line instead of desktop version: https://neo4j-contrib.github.io/neo4j-etl/

Comment: Adding indexes on key property values usually improves performance. https://neo4j.com/docs/cypher-manual/current/indexes-for-search-performance/